# use cox model to estimate survival

Tags: r, estimation, cox

I first establish a cox model in R:

```
test1<- test[1:20,]
model.1 <- coxph(Surv(test1$days,test1$status==1) ~ test1$MTT+test1$ADC,data=test1)
```

and when i tried to predict next patient's survival like this:

```
covs1 <- data.frame(test[21,]$MTT,test[21,]$ADC)
summary(survfit(model.1, newdata= covs1, type ="aalen"))
```

it gave me too many survival results and the warning is 
"'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 20 rows "
fyi, there are 20 events and the results contain 20 survival results.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the columns in the datframe being given as the basis for a prediction must have the same column names as are in the RHS of the model formula. I don't think yours will qualifiy unless you do something like this:

```
test1<- test[1:20,]
model.1 <- coxph( Surv(days, status==1) ~ MTT + ADC, data=test1)

covs1 <- test[21, c("MTT", "ADC")]
 # then do your prediction
```

You should not use `$` to supply arguments to Surv. It is important that the model be constructed in the environment of the dataframe.